# Python: tkinter, mysql, fitz и создание *.exe файла

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, exe, cx-freeze

Желание получить *.exe из Python привело к проблемам, описанным [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1218540/209304) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1110771/209304).
Понимаю невозможность дать ответ на вопросы такого типа, опишу свое понимание того, как из Python-кода нужно получать exe  файл. Может укажете на концептуальные промахи. Итак:

1. Доводим код до рабочего состояния. Проверяем как минимум запускаемость кода на всех ветках меню.
2. Выписываем все импортируемые модули (conda installed & pip installed)
3. Указываем путь tkinter dll(s) для ручного включения в копируемые файлы.  Тут я не знаю - что делать с моим mysql connect?
4. Передаем все в скрипт и ждем пока создастся.
5. Запускаю - на секунду мелькает черное окно и все закрывается без слов.
   Ну вот и код:

   ```
   '''Imports are automatically detected (normally) in the script to freeze  ))) '''
   cx_Freeze.setup(
       name="Name_1st_exe",
       description='My Hello World App!',
       options={
           "build_exe":
           {
           "packages": [
               "tkinter", "matplotlib",
               "functools",
               "json",
               "time", "datetime",
               "pathlib",
               "PIL",
               "winsound",
               "mysql",
               "PyPDF2",
               "fitz",
               'numpy', 'collections',
               'requests',
               'pprint',
               'abc',
           ],
           "include_files": [
               r"D:\OD\OneDrive\PyCodes\AnaPy\ICO\python-powered-h-140x182.ico",                    
               r"D:\Games\Anaconda\envs\postman\Library\bin\tcl86t.dll",
               r"D:\Games\Anaconda\envs\postman\Library\bin\tk86t.dll",
               # может, что то еще?
           ],
           'include_msvcr': True,
           }
       },
       version="0.2",
       executables=executables)
   ```

Могу добавить, что сборка делается на 10й винде для запуска на 10й винде.
Python = 3.9.7 все из под Anaconda.
Приходилось использовать `conda install some_modules -c conda-forge`.

Желанное меню tkinter увидеть так и не удалось )

Возможно проблема с желанием использовать `MySQL` в сборке, ну или модуль абстракных классов `abc` .  Был бы признателен, если кто поделится опытом создания таких сборок.

**Дополнено.**  Отзовитесь - у кого нибудь получался exe  из Tkinter+abc+mysql ?   Или я один такое пробую сделать...

Comment: Если полученные exe запустить через консоль, выводит какие-то ошибки? На всякий случай еще дам [ссылку](https://jenyay.net/Programming/Cxfreeze)

Comment: Запускается и молча падает

Comment: я бы проверил сначала на каком-то простом примере собрать exe, вполне возможно что ошибка не зависит от содержимого проекта, иначе нужно будет видимо больше подробностей с минимально воспроизводимым примером

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня была похожая проблема при конвертации через pyinstaller. Cкрипт ссылался на дополнительные исполняемые файлы при работе. Я решил это так:

1. В самом скрипте прописать относительный путь к исполняемым файлам пример -`parent_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))`
2. Запустить pyinstaller из командной  строки с атрибутом --onefile `pyinstaller --onefile my_script.py`
3. В файле my_script.spec(создается автоматически при первом запуске pyinstaller) нужно указать:

   ```
   a = Analysis(['my_script.py'],
   pathex=['C:\\project\\my_script.py'],
   binaries=[ ('C:\\project\\dir_file\\file.exe', '.\\dir_file\\file.exe') ],
   datas=None,
   ```
4. Запустить pyinstaller из командной строки с указанием файла конфигурации `pyinstaller myscript.spec my_script.py`

Решил основываясь на данном ответе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563851/how-to-include-chromedriver-with-pyinstaller

Comment: Спасибо, надо будет попробовать )